# hook_menu() wildcard problem

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I can't get the wildcard from a hook_menu to pass it to a callback function

Here is what I have:

```
function spin_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['spin/login/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'SPIN',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'page callback' => 'spin_check_access'
    );

    return $items;
}

function spin_check_access($type = '') {
    echo $type; // type is never the %
}
```

Is it correct? I need the $type to be replaced with the wildcard's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

```
function spin_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['spin/login'] = array(
    'title' => 'SPIN',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'spin_check_access',
  );

  $items['spin/login/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'SPIN',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'spin_check_access',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Hook menu will not send any wildcard params to the callback function, but it will send params not defined in the url. So in the first example if you go to `spin/login` type will be `''` and `spin/login/foo` type will be `foo`. For the second example `spin/login` will return 404 and for `spin/login/foo` type will be `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing page arguments, telling Drupal which values to pass on. Try:

```
$items['spin/login/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'SPIN',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'page callback' => 'spin_check_access'
);
```